# Reputation in meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On the main site, I can click my reputation at the top of the screen, next to my name, and it will take me to the appropriate page of my profile. On meta, however, it does not.

Answer (score 3):

When you click your profile on the main site, it takes you to your main profile. When you click your profile on meta, it takes you to your meta profile. On meta, you do not earn reputation; your meta profile inherits the reputation earned on the main site.

Comment: Still, shouldnt it take you to the page which shows you how you earned that rep, i.e. your main site profile reputation page?

Comment: No, because the meta profile page shows you important details specific to meta. Like your Q's/A's and activity specific to meta.